# Is there a map of Material design colors for Flutter?

Tags: colors, material-design, flutter

I have a widget that I'd ideally like to take in a base Material color and output a widget themed with shades of that color. For example:

```
return new Container(
  color: Colors.pink.shade50,
  child: new Text(
    'hello',
    style: new TextStyle(
      color: Colors.pink.shade100,
    ),
  ),
);
```

requires me to specify both shades of pink. Ideally, I could do something like:

```
Color color = getBaseColorForThisPage(); // returns something like Colors.pink, but on another page, it'll return something like Colors.purple
return new Container(
  color: color.shade50,
  child: new Text(
    'hello',
    style: new TextStyle(
      color: color.shade100,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is there a way to return a "map" of Material colors within a color palette, instead of just a single color? When I look at the autocomplete in IntelliJ, I see that after typing `Colors.pink`, I'm able to specify the shade. But if I set the color to a variable, e.g. `Color color = Colors.pink`, I am later not able to do `color.shade100` or `color[100]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MaterialColor` extends [`ColorSwatch`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ColorSwatch-class.html) which is kind of like a `Map` of colors. You can use `ColorSwatch` anywhere you could use a `Color` and get the 500 shade, but you can also index into it with `[]`.

To get a `List` of all the primary material color swatches, use [`Colors.primaries`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Colors/primaries-constant.html).

Comment: Do I have to define the map myself for the ColorSwatch, or is there a way to refer to the MaterialColor map? So far, this is the code snippet I have (apologize for formatting), where I have to manually define each shade of the color:
`var map = new Map<dynamic, Color>();
    map.putIfAbsent(50, () => Colors.pink[50]);
    map.putIfAbsent(100, () => Colors.pink[100]);
    var colorswatch = new ColorSwatch(500, map);
    // later setting color:
    // color: colorswatch[50]`
I tried to use a color from Colors.primaries but they return a MaterialColor instead of a Map.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a `Map` here. You can just say `ColorSwatch color = Colors.pink;` and you'll be able to say `color[50]` later. If you know all the swatches are `MaterialColor`, just use `MaterialColor` as the type for `color`.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had to instantiate a new ColorSwatch object (which takes in a Map)! I didn't realize I could just set a ColorSwatch object to an existing MaterialColor. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Sorry, I know this already has a lot of good answers but here's the naive implementation I've been using to turn any color into a material color in case anyone finds it useful:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Map<int, Color> getSwatch(Color color) {
  final hslColor = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  final lightness = hslColor.lightness;

  /// if [500] is the default color, there are at LEAST five
  /// steps below [500]. (i.e. 400, 300, 200, 100, 50.) A
  /// divisor of 5 would mean [50] is a lightness of 1.0 or
  /// a color of #ffffff. A value of six would be near white
  /// but not quite.
  final lowDivisor = 6;

  /// if [500] is the default color, there are at LEAST four
  /// steps above [500]. A divisor of 4 would mean [900] is
  /// a lightness of 0.0 or color of #000000
  final highDivisor = 5;

  final lowStep = (1.0 - lightness) / lowDivisor;
  final highStep = lightness / highDivisor;

  return {
    50: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness + (lowStep * 5))).toColor(),
    100: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness + (lowStep * 4))).toColor(),
    200: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness + (lowStep * 3))).toColor(),
    300: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness + (lowStep * 2))).toColor(),
    400: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness + lowStep)).toColor(),
    500: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness)).toColor(),
    600: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness - highStep)).toColor(),
    700: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness - (highStep * 2))).toColor(),
    800: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness - (highStep * 3))).toColor(),
    900: (hslColor.withLightness(lightness - (highStep * 4))).toColor(),
  };
}
```

The function just adds a relative amount of lightness both above and below your target color. Getting the final material color would be:

```dart
final materialColor = MaterialColor(color.value, getSwatch(color));
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, it's promising but unfortunately it doesn't generate a swatch identical to the real hardcoded material swatch, it's just a different swatch. I've tried it and realized that it seems right with a dark color (indigo) but looks completely wrong when applied to a light color (orange). Here's what I came up with to determine the corresponding MaterialColor based on a simple primary value Color: 
MaterialColor getMaterialSwatch(Color color) {
  return Colors.primaries.firstWhere((element) => element.value == color.value);
}

Comment: Yeah, apologies. I wrote this a while ago and found it better practice to not go around defining your own material colors anyways so I haven't checked or used it since. Feel free to create an answer and ping me and I'll link to it in this one if you care too

Comment: This is the better solution I found. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

If you take a look the Dart documentation about Flutter [here](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/flutter/0.0.40-dev/material/Colors/green-constant.html)

you will notice how some of the MaterialColor objects are created.

Obviously Flutter has really good conception about the MaterialDesign and most of the colours described [here](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette) are already predefined inside the main flutter package "package:flutter/material.dart". All this is going to be available to be used out of the box, but

If somebody still wants to create his own MaterialColor with specific shades you can do something like this:

```
MaterialColor myGreen = const MaterialColor(0xFFAAD400,
  const {
    50 : const Color(hex_value1),
    100 : const Color(hex_value2),
    200 : const Color(hex_value3),
    300 : const Color(hex_value4),
    400 : const Color(hex_value5),
    500 : const Color(hex_value6),
    600 : const Color(hex_value7),
    700 : const Color(hex_value8),
    800 : const Color(hex_value9),
    900 : const Color(hex_value10)});
```

The first parameter in MaterialColor object constructor is the default HEX value of your colour, in this case 0xFFAAD400. The second parameter is a Map with all swatches of your colour. All values about "hex_value1" .... "hex_value10" need to be different colours. To get some idea how to select (create) these swatches, for example take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)

For those who don't know how to read the colours HEX values, here I will post some additional information:

For example, to get a fully opaque orange (0xFFFF9000), you could use 
const Color(0xFFFF9000), where:

- first two characters (FF) are about the alpha (transparency),
- second two characters (FF) are for the red,
- third two characters (90) are for the green,
- and last two (00) for the blue.

Thanks, Hope it will help to somebody

Answer (score 3):

**You can create your material color just like this:**

```
const MaterialColor primaryColorShades = MaterialColor(
  0xFF181861,
  <int, Color>{
    50: Color(0xFFA4A4BF),
    100: Color(0xFFA4A4BF),
    200: Color(0xFFA4A4BF),
    300: Color(0xFF9191B3),
    400: Color(0xFF7F7FA6),
    500: Color(0xFF181861),
    600: Color(0xFF6D6D99),
    700: Color(0xFF5B5B8D),
    800: Color(0xFF494980),
    900: Color(0xFF181861),
  },
);
```

Answer (score 3):

We have to use a map for it:

If you want to create your own MaterialColor with specific shades you can do something like this by creating own map of color in RGBO(Red, Gree, Blue, Opacity) form:

```
Map<int, Color> colorMap = {
  50: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .1),
  100: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .2),
  200: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .3),
  300: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .4),
  400: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .5),
  500: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .6),
  600: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .7),
  700: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .8),
  800: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, .9),
  900: Color.fromRGBO(147, 205, 72, 1),
};
// Green color code: 93cd48 and first two characters (FF) are alpha values (transparency)
MaterialColor customColor = MaterialColor(0xFF93cd48, colorMap);
```

If you have color code value like **93cd48** then for converting it to RGB value use 
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html

For more reference: https://medium.com/@jits619/flutter-material-color-conversion-ad1574f25828

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U19hRU9e0yw&list=PLQ7fSTYH_bV06SWG1IPnyFbavN5NB_h2o&index=7&t=345s

Comment: Unfortunately this does not meet the specification that "The greater the index, the darker the color"

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create your own material color instead, its easy. I also use a simple website to pick colors for flutter. [Flutter Doctor Color Picker](https://flutter-color-picker.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: the website you posted cannot convert a color in hexadecimal to argb.

Comment: And the question is - How to convert a Color variable into MaterialColor?

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I've made a dart extension package that is super simple to use and creates perfect `MaterialColor` objects.
https://pub.dev/packages/material_color_gen

Super simple to use:

```dart
var newColor = Color(0xFF2929FF).toMaterialColor();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method I got from somewhere and I can't find where.  I also had to make a small tweak to get it to work on newer, null-safe version of Dart.

```
extension ColorConversion on Color {
  MaterialColor toMaterialColor() {
    final List strengths = <double>[.05];
    final Map<int, Color> swatch = {};
    final r = red, g = green, b = blue;

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      strengths.add(0.1 * i);
    }

    for (final strength in strengths) {
      final ds = 0.5 - strength;
      swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
        r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
        g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
        b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
        1,
      );
    }

    return MaterialColor(value, swatch);
  }
}
```