# how to add custom color to flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, flutter-layout

I want to change the color of AppBar and use a custom color for it, I tried many options but none seem to work.
Is there anything I'm missing?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final ThemeData CompanyThemeData = new ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
  accentColor: CompanyColors.black[500],
  accentColorBrightness: Brightness.light
);
  
class CompanyColors {
  CompanyColors._(); // this basically makes it so you can instantiate this class
 
 static const _blackPrimaryValue = 0xFF000000;

  static const MaterialColor black = const MaterialColor(
    _blackPrimaryValue,
    const <int, Color>{
      50:  const Color(0xFFe0e0e0),
      100: const Color(0xFFb3b3b3),
      200: const Color(0xFF808080),
      300: const Color(0xFF4d4d4d),
      400: const Color(0xFF262626),
      500: const Color(_blackPrimaryValue),
      600: const Color(0xFF000000),
      700: const Color(0xFF000000),
      800: const Color(0xFF000000),
      900: const Color(0xFF000000),
    },
  );
}
```

and then I have used it in main.dart as

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch:Theme1.CompanyColors.black[50],
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
```

but after execution it says

> type Color is not of subtype MaterialColor

Comment: refer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595466/is-there-a-map-of-material-design-colors-for-flutter/56279034#56279034

Answer (score 103):

basically flutter uses color `AARRGGBB` format you can use below color code with any color property like:

```
new Container(color: const Color(0xff2980b9));
```

AA = transparency

RR = red

GG = green

BB = blue

now if you want to create custom color 8-digit code from 6-digit color code then just append transparency (AA) value to it

Transparency percentages
Following are some example transparency percentages and their hex values

```
100% - FF
95% - F2
90% - E6
85% - D9
80% - CC
75% - BF
70% - B3
65% - A6
60% - 99
55% - 8C
50% - 80
45% - 73
40% - 66
35% - 59
30% - 4D
25% - 40
20% - 33
15% - 26
10% - 1A
5% - 0D
0% - 00
```

in my case i always use AA = ff because 6-digit color has ff transparency.
for 6-digit color [best site](https://coolors.co/)

Answer (score 39):

It's a `MaterialColor` object (not `Color`) you should assign for a swatch property, providing color values for the ten different luminances.

Many people suggested adjusting the alpha/opacity value of the colors used in the `MaterialColor`. It's actually a big mistake because it will result in making your element translucent without providing color variety of different shades.

Please consider using this solution for a better approach.

[Flutter: Creating a custom color swatch for MaterialColor](https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-custom-color-swatch-in-flutter-554bcdcb27f3)

```dart
MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
  List strengths = <double>[.05];
  final swatch = <int, Color>{};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }
  strengths.forEach((strength) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  });
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```

Answer (score 33):

There are several ways to do it, but [this](https://medium.com/py-bits/turn-any-color-to-material-color-for-flutter-d8e8e037a837) is the method I prefer to use. It's dead simple.

Create a custom

```
MaterialColor myColor = MaterialColor(0xFF880E4F, color);
```

Create a map and as you will see below that I modify the opacity channel from 50 through to 900 to give you the various color degrees of opacity.

```
Map<int, Color> color =
{
50:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .1),
100:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .2),
200:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .3),
300:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .4),
400:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .5),
500:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .6),
600:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .7),
700:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .8),
800:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, .9),
900:Color.fromRGBO(4,131,184, 1),
};
```

Same works for Color.fromRGBA if you prefer using Alpha over Opacity.

I would like to point out that I saw you were trying to do this.

```
primarySwatch: Colors.black[500]
```

This will give you the an error. You have to use the base MaterialColor you created. Using the color degree modifiers will make the compiler unhappy.

Comment: Its helpful, but i'm not sure if opacity is really something a designer wants in his color shades. Imagine placing one color on a layer with another color. It gets mixed.

Answer (score 28):

You can create a Seprate class.

```
static const PrimaryColor =  Color(0xFF808080);
static const PrimaryAssentColor =  Color(0xFF808080);
static const PrimaryDarkColor =  Color(0xFF808080);
static const ErroColor =  Color(0xFF808080);
```

Answer (score 22):

You shouldn't have `[50]` on the end of here:

```
primarySwatch:Theme1.CompanyColors.black[50]
```

Just use the `MaterialColor` object you created:

```
primarySwatch:Theme1.CompanyColors.black
```

I tested this by creating a `MaterialColor` that's all red, and it worked fine:

[image: Red color]

Answer (score 18):

It's pretty simple.

Get `HEX` code of your custom color. You can either use a color picker like [ColorZilla](https://www.colorzilla.com/) or google. Note that `HEX` codes are not case sensitive. I prefer capital.

One example of `HEX` code would look like `#0077CC`.

Replace `#` with `0xFF`, so it becomes  `0xFF0077CC`

Your custom color is ready `Color(0xFF0077CC)`

Comment: I already had what I wanted, what was missing was the `0xFF` part, android studio was suggesting `0x000`

Answer (score 6):

`primarySwatch` is of type `MaterialColor` and you are passing a value of type `Color` to it.

You either may try this

```
primarySwatch:Theme1.CompanyColors.black,
```

Or use `primaryColor` property instead

```
primaryColor:Theme1.CompanyColors.black[50],
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a common class like a below code snippet:

```
  class ColorConstants {
  static const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF394497);
  static const kSecondaryColor = Color(0xFF444FAB);
  static const kThirdSecondaryColor = Color(0xFF5E6BD8);
  static const kGravishBlueColor = Color(0xFF9BA1D2);
  }
```

To use specific color snippet will look like a below:

```
color: ColorConstants.kPrimaryColor
```

Answer (score 5):

I just created a website where you can pick Flutter Colors for your app. You can use that to pick any color you want [Flutter Doctor Color Picker](https://flutter-color-picker.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I saw this a while aga, not I come to look at it again and the post has been removed :(

Comment: @SamKelham I believe the post is still here since you're replying to it. If you're interested to see the website again. ------> https://flutter-color-picker.herokuapp.com/

Comment: How can I go from for example #ff2200 to the ARGB equivalent please

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have a deep customization in mind for your MaterialColor and the defaults are just fine then this works out pretty nice and it's simple:

```
static MaterialColor generateMaterialColorFromColor(Color color) {
    return MaterialColor(color.value, {
      50: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.1),
      100: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.2),
      200: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.3),
      300: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.4),
      400: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.5),
      500: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.6),
      600: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.7),
      700: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.8),
      800: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 0.9),
      900: Color.fromRGBO(color.red, color.green, color.blue, 1.0),
    });
  }
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
var materialColor = generateMaterialColorFromColor(Colors.red);
```

or

```
// color format is ARGB
var materialColor = generateMaterialColorFromColor(Color(0xFFFF0000));
```

Answer (score 5):

You try:

Convert Hex Color to MaterialColor (Flutter)
: http://mcg.mbitson.com/

Details:
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I used a simple int parser by selecting appropriate color palette in hex code define it as a string in int-parser with a "0xff" predecessor in place of "#"  and got the solution,
my actual hex color code was #7CEA9C. It is nothing but as follows

```
    color: Color(int.parse("0xff7CEA9C")),
```

Comment: You can also use `color: Color(xff7CEA9C)`. `0xff7CEA9C` is a valid int literal in dart.

Answer (score 2):

First create a `createMaterialColor.dart` file:

**createMaterialColor.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateMaterialColor{
  MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
    List strengths = <double>[.05];
    final swatch = <int, Color>{};
    final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      strengths.add(0.1 * i);
    }
    strengths.forEach((strength) {
      final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
      swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
        r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
        g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
        b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
        1,
      );
    });
    return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
  }

}
```

Now, in the .dart file where you want to use custom color, say `first.dart`, first add this:

```dart
import '<path_to>/createMaterialColor.dart';
```

then, inside the class of stateless widget, initialize the class first like this:

```dart
final createMaterialColor = CreateMaterialColor();
```

Now you can use this function to generate custom color in `first.dart` like this (for eg if the custom color code is `#ffffff`):

```dart
createMaterialColor.createMaterialColor(Color(0xFFffffff))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day; not only a customized solution but also a dynamic one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Colors _thisColor = Color(0xFF3366FF);
```

Answer (score 1):

add the below part to the section(button,container..) which you want to change the color.

```
color: Color(0xFFffd57e),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in Appear called backgroundColor. Use this to set any colour for your Appbar. You don't need to change the theme.

Comment: Sorry you can't give any color to `AppBar`. It has to be completely opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Although shade is a list of integer indexes and color options, it is also a property of your `CompanyColors` object so you have to reference it differently than a list. And I'm not an expert on flutter and dart but I'm not sure what the `Theme1` is for.

```
//instead of this...    
primarySwatch: Theme1.CompanyColors.black[50]

//do this by accessing the shade property of the Colors.black object
//and drop the theme1 thing...allegedly ;)

primarySwatch: CompanyColors.black.shade(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          color: const Color(0xFFF57F17),
    
    
     Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xFFF57F17),
                 borderRadius:
                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                 ),
                child: Text(
                            "Pending",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                            style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                           color: HexColor(
                           HexColor.gray_text),
                          fontFamily:
                          'montserrat_regular',
                          decoration:
                          TextDecoration.none,
                          ),
                      ),
 )
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
new Color(0xAARRGGBB)
```

https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/lib/ui/painting.dart